# Avoid storing passwords in plaintext for IMAP access via Python

Tags: python, imap, exchange-server, imaplib

I'm trying to write a script that helps to clear IMAP inboxes, and I'm running into a problem with passwords; namely, that to get access to the server I need to have access to the plaintext. I've checked, and my mailserver isn't showing MD5 as an available method (otherwise I could use `IMAP4.login_cram_md5`). How do I go about accessing the server without plaintext passwords?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the authentication methods available like this (I'm using `IMAP4_SSL`, use `IMAP4` if you want an insecure connection, but I don't recommend ever using non-SSL connections if you have the choice).

```
import imaplib
imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.server.com")
print "\n".join(i for i in imap_server.capabilities if i.startswith("AUTH="))
```

You can then write an authentication object that can be passed to `imap_server.authenticate()` for your chosen method. [This bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue13700) happens to have some examples of its use and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963820/gmail-imap-authentication-imaplib-authenticate-takes-exactly-3-args-4-given) shows someone authenticating via OAuth to Gmail.

If the server doesn't provide any authentication methods other than plaintext passwords, or you can't / don't wish to support them, then storing the password in a form where you can recover the plaintext is unfortunately unavoidable. You could encrypt it in some form (e.g. AES using [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/), example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778304/simple-example-aes256-crypt)), but the encryption key is still going to be stored somewhere unless you want to prompt the user each time (in which case you might as well just prompt for the password anyway). I would suggest at least some trivial obfuscation, such as Base64 encoding, just to prevent someone idly glancing at the code or config seeing the password in the clear.

**EDIT:** One other point which might be obvious is to make sure that if you do need to store plaintext passwords, you never store them in a file which needs to be world-readable. For example, don't ever hard-code them in scripts even if it's just a quick script which has all its other settings as global variables or similar. Instead, try to make sure the password is in a separate file which can have OS-specific permissions restricted as required.

Comment: You're quite welcome, sorry I didn't have a better solution for you. I'm just amending my answer to also mention keeping passwords out of source code (might be obvious, but important enough to mention I think).

Comment: Appreciate it; I'm already doing that now. What's best practice wrt. putting these files in git repos (not publically facing ones, of course)?

Comment: Storing passwords in Git repositories? Well, *best* practice would be "don't". If at all possible make it a piece of local configuration which never leaves the current machine. If need be, you can always have a dummy default value in Git and have a local uncommitted change on each checkout with the real password - you can always stash this to do other work and unstash afterwards. If you really *must* store the password in Git, make sure it's at least trivially encrypted (e.g. Base64) and in its own file. Avoid committing changes to that file with any other change.